# Bash keyword argument with multiple values

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm using this to get keyword arguments for my shell script

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  key="$1"
  case $key in
    -u) 
      USERID="$2"
      shift # past argument
      shift # past value
      ;;
    -n)
      JOBNAME="$2"
      shift # past argument
      shift # past value
      ;;
    -j) 
      job="$2"
      shift # past argument
      shift # past value
      ;;
      *) echo "Improper usage"; exit 1;;
  esac
done
```

Now the `job` variable usually is multi-word. I can give the whole value for that argument inside a quote and it works perfectly. But is it possible to provide the value without any quote but still store inside that single variable. For example, this works

```
./myscript -j "my long string"
```

and it stores `"my long string"` to the variable `job`. But I want this to work too similarly,

```
./myscript -j my long string
```

Comment: My question is, why? It's possible tho, but why?

Comment: how about concatenating  $2 $3 $4 $...

Comment: Don't. That would be contrary to all the usual customs for command line arg processing, and might make some users really confused. Also you'd have issues if you ever need to take other args after the job string, `./myscript -j "foo bar" file.txt` is clear, but `./myscript -j foo bar file.txt` is ambiguous. Or with other options, where does the string end in: `./myscript -j foo bar -u user`? You could decide the next arg starting with a dash ends the string and is itself taken as an option, but then you'd be limiting the allowed set of values in the job string.

Answer (score 3):

You could pick the remaining parameters with `"$*"`, but I really wouldn't recommend it. The standard expectation is that option flags should take no more than a single parameter value.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
progname="${0##*/}"
usage="Usage: $progname -u <userid> -n <jobname> -j <job>"

while getopts ':u:n:j:' OPT
do
    case "$OPT" in
        u)      userid="$OPTARG" ;;
        n)      jobname="$OPTARG" ;;
        j)      job="$OPTARG" ;;
        ?)      echo "$usage" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# Append any remaining arguments to the job
[[ $# -gt 0 ]] && job="${job:+$job }$*"

printf "userid=%s, jobname=%s, job=%s.\n" "$userid" "$jobname" "$job"
exit 0
```

To stay within standard expectations, do not include the line that appends remaining arguments to the job.